# Grails Shared Custom Validator

Tags: customvalidator

I have multiple domain objects with differently names start and end dates. I would like to create a shared custom validator that accepts two dates and validates them.

All the documentation seems to state the second argument in the validator closure is the current object. Is there a way to do the following? If so how would the constraint closure in the domain object look?

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    '*'(nullable: true)
    endDateValidator(
        validator: { endDateValue, startDateValue ->
            if(!(endDateValue?.after(startDateValue))){
                return 'end.date.before.start.date.error'
            }
            else{
                return true
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you still need to create a validator for each domain class since each of them has differently named properties. However, you can share the validation business logic among these validators.

---

Example:

The shared validation logic would go to a `static boolean validateDateOrdering(Date first, Date second)` method and validators might look like:

```
 fooValidator(
    validator: { value, domainInst ->
         validateDateOrdering(value, domainInst['bar'])
    }
 )
 barValidator(
    validator: { value, domainInst ->
         validateDateOrdering(domainInst['foo'], value)
    }
 )
```